# Why is AVAudioPlayer failing to initialise? With OSStatus error 1685348671?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am recording audio in a view controller (a voice memo). This works. I can play back the recorded audio as long as the user doesn't dismiss the view controller.

However, if the user dismisses the view controller, and opens the view controller again, initialising the AVAudioPlayer fails with OSStatus error 1685348671.

**I also tried to init the player with NSData: 
        `NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_outputFileURL];
        _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error2];`, but that would not work either**

I have tried .caf, followed every tutorial, but somehow I can not make it work...
This error seems to refer to invalid file or so, though I am not sure. However if I download the app in the Organizer and open it on my Mac, I can play it, so the file itself is not corrupted.

Here is my record method:

```
- (IBAction)recordPauseTapped:(id)sender {
    // Stop the audio player before recording
    if (_player.playing) {
        [_player stop];
    }
    if (!_recorder.recording) {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive:YES error:nil];

        // Start recording
        [_recorder record];
        [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

    // Pause recording
        [_recorder pause];
        [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Aufnahme" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [stopButton setEnabled:YES];
    [playButton setEnabled:NO];
 }
```

Recording works, and the file exists in the Documents directory.

Here is my play method, which works if the file was recorded immediately before, with without the user leaving the view controller:

```
- (IBAction)playTapped:(id)sender {
    if (!_recorder.recording){

        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

        NSError *error;
        BOOL success = [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"error doing outputaudioportoverride - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        NSError *error2;
        NSLog(@"_outputFileURL: %@", _outputFileURL);

        _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_outputFileURL error:&error2];
        if (error2) {
            NSLog(@"error initialising player - %@", [error2 localizedDescription]);
         }
        [_player setDelegate:self];
        [_player play];
    }
}
```

And here is my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    [stopButton setEnabled:NO];

    // Set the audio file
    if ([_audioFileName isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSString *guid = [[NSUUID new] UUIDString];
        _audioFileName = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"audio-%@.m4a", guid];
        [playButton setEnabled:NO];
    } else {
        [playButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
    NSLog(@"_audioFileName: %@", _audioFileName);
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           _audioFileName,
                           nil];
    _outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    _recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:_outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    _recorder.delegate = self;
    _recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [_recorder prepareToRecord];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have [_recorder prepareToRecord]; into the viewLoad, which means that
it will be overwritten each time that you load the view controller. 
If you don't wish this behaviour you should remove this line and put it at the beginning of
recordPauseTapped for example.
That should fix your issues.